# Having both text AND href links inside a select / combo-box

Tags: javascript, html

I have read [Links in  dropdown options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27031475/using-href-links-inside-option-tag-to-link-to-url) and [using href links inside  tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000656/using-href-links-inside-option-tag) and several other questions in SO, however my question is a bit different.

I would like to have BOTH text AND href inside a select combo-box.
Something like

```
<select id="mySelect">    
    <option value="-1" selected>choose an option to test</option>    
    <option value="1">Book 1 <a href="http://example.com/23?id=12">open site</a></option>    
    <option value="2">Book 2 <a href="http://example.com/11?id=10">open site</a></option> 
</select>
```

The idea is that the user can select from a combo-box, but also can go to an external site  by clicking `open site`  to view the Books before selecting them.

[image: Something like this]
ie: clicking on the left-side of the `<option>` is a regular select, while clicking on the right-side of the `<option>` will send the user to another page

Is that possible? Running the code either ignores completely the href or complains `Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <a> cannot appear as a child of <option>.`

Comment: You can check out jquery select2 library. That may allow you to do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

> Is that possible?

Not using using `<a>` element as child element of `<option>` element; `<a>` element is not a valid child node of HTML [`<option>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) element.

> **Permitted content** Text, possibly with escaped characters (like é).

You can set the URL at the element `data-*` attribute and navigate to the URL at `change` event of `<select>` element

```js
document.getElementById("mySelect")
.onchange = function() {
   var url = this.selectedOptions[0].dataset.href;
   if (url && confirm("Navigate to " + url + "?")) {
     location.href = url;
   }
}
```

```css
:target {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">    
    <option value="-1" selected>choose an option to test</option>    
    <option value="1" data-href="#Book1">Book 1 </option>    
    <option value="2" data-href="#Book2">Book 2 </option> 
</select>

<div id="Book1">Book 1</div>
<div id="Book2">Book 2</div>
```

Comment: but that will not enable to use the `select` both as `option` AND as `link`.
IE: clicking on the left-side of the `option` is a regular select, while clicking on the right-side of the `option` will send the user to another page

Comment: @rafahoro You can alternatively use `<ul>` and `<li>` elements to achieve requirement, see [Displaying color in dropdown control using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35692330/displaying-color-in-dropdown-control-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Fit.UI's Drop down control for that. The display value may contain HTML elements such as a link.

http://fitui.org/Control-DropDown.html